# Why does GCC insist non-leaf callees copy CBV structs to the stack?

Tags: optimization, gcc, call, cpu-registers

Consider the following C99 code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct baz { uint64_t x, y; };

uint64_t foo(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, struct baz c)
{
    return a + b + c.x + c.y;
}

void bar(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, struct baz c)
{
    printf("%lu\n", a);
}
```

The behavior I expect, when compiled with `gcc -O3`, is that `c` is passed in registers to both `foo` and `bar`, is accessed using registers in `foo`, and is entirely ignored in `bar`.  GCC produces code which does this for `foo`.  However, in `bar`, `c` is copied from registers to the stack, and is then promptly ignored:

```
    .file   "pbv.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl foo
    .type   foo, @function
foo:
.LFB22:
    .cfi_startproc
    leaq    (%rcx,%rdx), %rdx
    leaq    (%rdx,%rdi), %rdi
    leaq    (%rdi,%rsi), %rax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE22:
    .size   foo, .-foo
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "%lu\n"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl bar
    .type   bar, @function
bar:
.LFB23:
    .cfi_startproc
    movq    %rdx, -24(%rsp)
    movl    $.LC0, %esi
    movq    %rdi, %rdx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $1, %edi
    movq    %rcx, -16(%rsp)
    jmp __printf_chk
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE23:
    .size   bar, .-bar
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.6-11ubuntu2) 4.4.6"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

(Note that `a` and `b` are passed in `%rsi` and `%rdi`, and `c` is passed in `%rcx` and `%rdx`.)

The only reason I can surmise for this is some sort of ABI requirement (e.g. for interaction with longjmp).  I cannot find any optimization (`-f`) options for GCC, nor GCC-specific annotations which inhibit this behavior.  Annotating `c` with `register` does not help.

This happens with different targets as well.  (Notably, on the TileGX, `foo` has space allocated and deallocated on the stack, but nothing is stored there.)  I have tested both GCC 4.4.6 and 4.6.1.

Is this expected behavior or a bug in GCC?  Either way, is there some way to work around it (beside using call-by-reference or ensuring `bar` can be a leaf)?

Answer (score 0):

This shortcoming is the same as mentioned in bug [44194](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44194), the patch for which is present in the very latest version of GCC (4.7.2).

The cause is roughly that the call to `printf` (or any function) is considered to be able to access anything in memory, including stack-based locals.  The patch causes stack-based locals not to be considered reachable by the callee.